# I am trying to solve one of the assignments on Coursera from Fundamentals of Parallelism on Intel Architecture course

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, intel-mkl

```
#include <mkl.h>
#include <hbwmalloc.h>


//implement scratch buffer on HBM and compute FFTs 
void runFFTs( const size_t fft_size, const size_t num_fft, MKL_Complex8 *data, DFTI_DESCRIPTOR_HANDLE *fftHandle) {
    //const long buff_size = 1000;
    const long buff_size = 1<<27;

    MKL_Complex8 *buff;
    hbw_posix_memalign((void**) &buff, 4096, sizeof(MKL_Complex8)*buff_size);

     for(size_t i = 0; i < num_fft; i++) {


        #pragma omp parallel for
        for(size_t j=0; j < (fft_size+2)*num_fft; j++)
        for(size_t j=0; j< fft_size; j++){
            buff[j].real = data[i*fft_size+j].real;
            buff[j].imag = data[i*fft_size+j].imag;
        }

        //DftiComputeForward (*fftHandle, &data[i*fft_size]);
        DftiComputeForward (*fftHandle, buff);

        #pragma omp parallel for
        for(size_t j=0; j< fft_size; j++){
            data[i*fft_size+j].real = buff[j].real;
            data[i*fft_size+j].imag = buff[j].imag;
        }


    }

    hbw_free(buff);

}
```

I am stuck with verification of the code. It seems copy operation from Data to buff HBM buffer is giving issues. Can anybody figure out where is the issue in the code.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has a wrong statement:

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for(size_t j=0; j < (fft_size+2)*num_fft; j++)
for(size_t j=0; j< fft_size; j++){
```

the second `for` is repeated `(fft_size+2)*num_fft` times.

here is a solution

```
  for(size_t i = 0; i < num_fft; i++) {
      
    # pragma omp parallel for 
    for(size_t j = 0; j < fft_size; j++){
      buff[j].real = data[i*fft_size + j].real;
      buff[j].imag = data[i*fft_size + j].imag;
    }
      
    DftiComputeForward (*fftHandle, buff);
      
    # pragma omp parallel for
    for(size_t j = 0; j < fft_size; j++){
      data[i*fft_size + j].real = buff[j].real;
      data[i*fft_size + j].imag = buff[j].imag;
    }
  }
```